# Solution to this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have troubles solving this equation. I tried to move on, but nothing was really useful.

$$  1 = \binom{n}{3} \left(\frac12\right)^{n-2}$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Simple trial and error gets the job done.

Comment: The equation is equivalent to $2^{n-2}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$, which is satisfied for $n=4$ over the integers. Do they care about real solutions? Complex?

Comment: The numerator on the right of Hellen's has a factor of $3$, but not $9$ nor any other odd primes, so there isn't much choice.

Comment: I would need an exact solution, they don't accept trial.

Comment: Given ${n \choose 3} = \frac {n!}{3!(n-3)!}$ can we assume $n$ is a natural number $\ge 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wee bit of manipulation and we get

${n \choose 3} = 2^{n-2}$ or

$\frac {(n-2)(n-1)n}{6} = 2^{n-2}$

$n(n-1)(n-2) = 2^{n-1}*3$

So $n, n-1, n+2$ must have no other factors than $2$ or $3$.  A and there must be exactly one power of $3$ as a factor.  So the only possible odd numbers among $n, n-1,$ and $n-2$ (of which there must be at least one) allowed would be $3$ or $1$.  Assuming $n\ge 3$ and natural (*Is* that an assumption?) we must have at least one odd and it must be greater than one. So we can only have one odd and it must equal $3$.

Furthermore the two other terms must be even and they must powers of $2$.

Hence the only possible odd among $n, n-1, n-2$ is equal to $3$.   $n, n-2$ have the same parity so they must be even and $n-1$ must be odd and $n-1 =3$.

This is good as $n=4$ and $n-2 = 2$  are powers of $2$ (and that is the only two powers of $2$ where $2^k - 2^m = 2$).  $\frac {2*3*4}6 = 4 = 2^2 = 2^{4-2}$ so this is the only acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your expression yields $$2^n=\dfrac{2}{3}n(n-1)(n-2)$$ and clearly $n=4$ is the only integer solution. However there are two other real solutions of this equation given approximately by $$-0.1668684918692626814441173808364929507849837416$$ and $$13.93856023297568362803948004939032501849896848.$$

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2%5Ex-(2%2F3)x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+from+x%3D-10+to+x%3D15) you can find a sketch of the graph of $f(x)=2^x-\dfrac{2x}{3}(x-1)(x-2)$ on domain $[-10, 15].$